# Custom UIAlertView: CODialog showing at top left corner

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, uialertview, custom-view

I'm using [CODialog](https://github.com/eaigner/CODialog) for my custom UIAlertView and it works (meaning it pops up), but my problem is that it's not popping up in the center of the screen, and after popup the buttons don't function. I implemented it just how it is in the sample file but can't seem to find the problem.

I added "CODialog.h" & "CODialog.m" to my project. Then did the following:

**ViewController.h File:**

```
 #import "CODialog.h"
```

...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CODialog * dialog
```

...

```
@synthesize dialog;

- (void) viewDidLoad{
self.dialog = [CODialog dialogWithWindow:self.view.window];
}

- (void)showDefault:(id)sender {  
  [self.dialog resetLayout];

  self.dialog.dialogStyle = CODialogStyleDefault;
  self.dialog.title = @"Title";
  self.dialog.subtitle = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

  [self.dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Done" target:self selector:@selector(hideDialog:)];
  [self.dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Ok" target:self selector:@selector(hideDialog:) highlighted:YES];
  [self.dialog showOrUpdateAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)hideDialog:(id)sender {
  [self.dialog hideAnimated:YES];
}
```

With **showDefault** being called by another method. I'm targeting iOS5 - iOS6 and using storyboard with ARC. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What about:

self.dialog = [CODialog dialogWithWindow:self.navigationController.view.window];

It'd fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the .center property of that view to half size of parent view ?

Comment: No I haven't tried that, but I ended up using [TSAlertView](https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView) instead. It was easy to implement and had no issues right off the bat. Including very customizable with .png images. Thanks tho, I'll try it anyway.